# Use htaccess to add HTML suffix to a joomla article

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, joomla

the issue is this:

I have some articles that need to have an .html suffix but when I add them the system throws me an 404 error, is there any way to add this without the error?

the html suffix needs to be present only on certain articles not in the whole site.

Comment: You really need to give more information about what you have tried, but why don't you instead use the core config setting but override it using a plugin for the ones you want to change?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i've activated the option that adds an html suffix but it adds it in every page, i don't need it in every page, just for one category articles, i've tryed to do this via htaccess with no succes so far

Comment: What I am saying is that you might be able to use  a system plugin to check the request to see whether you are in a given category and in that place have the plugin change the configuration to use the suffix or possibly use a custom router to add the segment at the end of the url.  That's assuming you handle it as a coding problem and not a configuration problem. I mean in truth you can just manually add .html to the end of any sef url and it will work just fine. The text is all just sugar. You are not redirecting at all by adding the string to the end.

Comment: Thank you very much i will follow your advice, i'll let you know!!!